# Error CREATing SolrCore schema fieldtype

Tags: apache, solr

Error CREATEing SolrCore 'association': Unable to create core [association] Caused by: schema fieldtype location_rpt(org.apache.solr.schema.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) invalid arguments:{units=degrees} This is error when i try to add a new core.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, there is no valid parameter named `units` for the `SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType` type. This is referenced in a field named `location_rpt` in your schema. Remove the parameter (and find out why it was set, and if that's going to cause any issues in the future - if you're not using spatial search, you should be good to go).

You can find [the parameters accepted by SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType on the Spatial Search page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search) in the community wiki.

Comment: I used an other collection cause i use the lastest version of solr. I just copy and modify correctly schema.xml solrconfig.xml and data-config.xml